# 1.0545E-6 перевод такого типа чисел в полные

Tags: php

Как перевести при помощи php 
1.0545E-6 такого рода числа в полный формат с 10 числами после запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте **[number_format](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)**

Его синтаксис:

```
string number_format (float $number, int $decimals = 0, string $dec_point = ".", string $thousands_sep = ",")
```

где:

- `number` - Форматируемое число.
- `decimals` - Устанавливает число знаков после запятой.
- `dec_point` - Устанавливает разделитель дробной части.
- `thousands_sep` - Устанавливает разделитель тысяч.

---

В итоге

```
echo number_format(1.0545E-6,10,'.',',');
```

выведет

```
0.0000010545
```

Answer (score 1):

Использовать [printf](https://php.ru/manual/function.printf.html). Примеры:

просто выводим дробное число: `printf("%f",$dd);` Вывод: **0.000001**

округление до 10ти знаков после запятой: `printf("%.10f",$dd);` Вывод: **0.0000010545**